# Display image from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

Would like to ask if anyone has ever tried to display an image from a Laravel Controller. Below is my code to a Laravel Controller. So basically I just want to hide the actual url of image and add additional validation so I decided to the image call my laravel URL.

## Blade code that call the laravel controller

```
<img src="/image/1">
```

## Route

```
Route::get('/image/{image_id}', ['as' => 'site.viewImage', 'uses' => 'ImageController@viewImage']);
```

## Controller

```
public function viewImage($image_id)
{
    return Storage::get($image_id . '.png');
}
```

But this return an error not-found. Am I doing something wrong here?
Note: I'm passing it to the controller because I need to do additional valdiation and to obfuscate the actual url of the file

I tried this code and its working but I would like a laravel type of approach

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo Storage::get($image_id .'.png');exit;
```

I also tried this approach

```
$response = response()->make(Storage::get($image_id . '.png'), 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", 'image/png');
return $response;
```

The laravel approach throws a 404 error.

Comment: Were you able to hit controller when you call the URL? Like try dd('testing') under controller and see whether you can view testing

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar yes I was able to hit it. But if I copy the url of the image let say http://mysite/image/1 then it throws a 404 error

Comment: Strange, if you are getting 404 error while copying the url and pasting it separate tab then when were you able to hit controller?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar I tried doing a dd(Storage::get("123.png")); and was ablee to get a response of bytes content of the image. Meaning its working its just that it throws an error after that Maximum execution error

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried

```
return response()->file($filePath);
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-responses

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show file from public folder

```
$link=url('link/to/image/'.$imageName);
header("Content-type: image/png");
$imageContent = file_get_contents($link);
echo $imageContent; 
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you can do something like this in Laravel 9.x.

Blade:

```
<img src="/image/1">
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/image/{id}', [ImageController::class, 'viewImage']);
```

Controller:

```
public function viewImage($id)
{
    // $image_path would look something like this: './images/abc.png'
    $image_path = $id.'.png';
    return response()->file( $image_path );
}
```